# Cannot Read Property Map of Undefined--Twitter API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

Hi all I'm fairly new to React so please tread lightly :0)

I'm trying to create a simple React app, in which a user can enter a search term, and a list of Tweets is populate.  Just fleshing this out right now using the Node Twit app.  I'm getting a 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' on a map function in the part where I'm trying to list out the tweets.

Here's where I'm running the map function in my 'Twitter' Component.

```
render() {
        const tweets = this.state.tweets;
        return (
          <div>
          {tweets.statuses.map(tweet =>
                <div key={tweet.objectID}>
                <span>
                    {tweet.text}
                </span>
                </div>    
          )}
            )};
         </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I know this has to be an issue with how I'm fetching the data--but have never worked with the Twitter API, so hoping someone might have some input---here's where I do that:

```
 performSearch = (searchTerm) => {
       T.get('search/tweets', {q: {searchTerm}})
       .then((err,data,response) => {
           let tweets = this.state.data;
           this.setState({
               tweets
           });
           console.log(tweets);
       })
       .catch(err=>{
           console.log('Error happened fetching data');
       });
    }
```

I'm also running this search function when the component mounts, like so

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.performSearch();
    }
```

And not sure if matters but variable 'tweets' is set on initial state as []

```
class Twitter extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tweets: [],
            searchTerm: this.props.searchTerm
    }
   }
```

If you need any more code for this to make more sense--just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Your code tries to look to `tweets.statuses` but the initial state is an empty array, thus has no `statuses` attribute and returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you call this function in `WillMount` this will work!

because in `DidMount`  your component already have been called the `render()` method and the current value of `statuses` is `undefined`.

or you can try some approuch like this:

```
render() {
        const tweets = this.state.tweets;
        return (
          <div>
          {tweets.statuses &&
            tweets.statuses.map(tweet =>
                <div key={tweet.objectID}>
                <span>
                    {tweet.text}
                </span>
                </div>    
          )}
            )};
         </div>
        );
    }
}
```

hope this could help you!